# Elasticsearch suggester filter by certain condition

Tags: elasticsearch, search-suggestion

My query as below

```
{
  "suggest": {
    "text": "iphame",
    "0-title": {
      "phrase": {
        "field": "title",
        "query": {
          "term": {
            "country_id": 123
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "1-subtitle": {
      "phrase": {
        "field": "subtitle"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want the search suggestion filter based on **country**, but the query above caused `parsing_exception`.

How to make the query look for title only based on certain country?

```
| id | title                   | subtitle    | country_id |
|----|-------------------------|-------------|------------|
| 1  | Cheapest iPhone in town | Lorem ipsum | 123        |
| 2  | iOS 13 beta released    | Lorem ipsum | 25         |
| 3  | iPadOS public beta      | Lorem ipsum | 123        |
```

E.g. I don't want include the `id = 2`.

Comment: Hey Js Lim, were you able to find a solution for this problem? I'm also looking at something similar, and I even tried browsing the source code, but do not see a way to do this yet.

Comment: @VarunNatraaj not figure out yet. I posted a [question here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/suggester-filter-by-certain-condition/189647), only you reply. I guess probably this feature not yet available.

Comment: @VarunNatraaj and Js Lim, did you ever work out how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

if you mapped country_id as a number then:

```
{ 
"query": { 
    "match": { 
            "country_id": 123 
        } 
    }
}
```

if you mapped country_id as a keyword then:

```
{ 
"query": { 
    "match": { 
            "country_id.keyword": "123" 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: For normal query result, this is workable. But I'm looking for `suggest`, the [Did you mean](https://qbox.io/blog/how-to-build-did-you-mean-feature-with-elasticsearch-phrase-suggester) feature.

Comment: Are you referring to something like FuzzySearch?

Comment: Is not fuzzy search. Fuzzy search only applicable to `query` if not mistaken. I just want to apply filter in **suggester**